# How does ASP MVC 4 know which db migration you're on?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have been developing my app in a code-first approach atop an exisiting database.

Only now do I have a need to run a migration. I don't want to destroy this database when my model changes because it is very large and it has nice sample data in it.

How can I run a migration without the framework telling me that there are pending changes to apply? (The code runs anyway as I do my migrations from Rails-tho I would like to do them from here)

I do not want to set up automatic migrations because I am working on a big database with lots of seeded data that I do not want to delete/recreate. I also want to have control over what is made, deleteded and when.

This is also needed for when I take it to production, I'd like to roll out the changes via Migration instead of manually. How can I migrate by adding in/removing the fields I want and not have EF care about what it is I do?

If I know how it knows which one it is on (like Rails) can I trick her into thinking that she can run the migrations I want?

I thought that setting the initializer by:

```
Database.SetInitializer<MyDbContext>(new CreateDatabaseIfNotExists<MyDbContext>
```

would take acre of it, but it does not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer the question in the title, because there's a sys table `__MigrationHistory` which tells EF that there is a difference in your tables vs what the database has.

As far as how to do it (from package manager console):

- `Enable-Migrations`

  - In the configuration class set `AutomaticMigrations = false;`
  - Set your `Database.SetInitializer<Context>(null)` so it doesn't DropCreate or Update
- `AddMigration <name>` to queue any pending changes to a change model
- `Update-Database` will call the `MigrationName.Up` method to alter the database with any changes (sans losing data).

Answer (score 1):

There's a Table "__MigrationHistory" that EF uses to store Migration Name / Order. You can backup this table in your dev environment, then delete these records. When you deploy to production, you run the migrations. Another option is use Database compare (dev / prod) and get scripts to change your tables / data.